# AFNetworking: downloading files in queue

Tags: iphone, queue, afnetworking

I just started using AFNetworking and so far it worked fine for just getting data from the web.

But now I have a list of files that need to be downloaded to the device

```
for(NSDictionary *issueDic in data)
{
    Issue *issue = [[Issue alloc] init];
    ...
    [self getOrDownloadCover:issue];
    ...
}
```

getOrDownloadCover:issue checks if a file already exists locally, if it does, it just saves that path, if it doesn't, it downloads the file from a given url

```
- (void)getOrDownloadCover:(Issue *)issue
{
    NSLog(@"issue.thumb: %@", issue.thumb);

    NSString *coverName = [issue.thumb lastPathComponent];

    NSLog(@"coverName: %@", coverName);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    __block NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:coverName];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        // Cover already exists
        issue.thumb_location = filePath;

        NSLog(@"issue.thumb_location: %@", filePath);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"load thumb");

        // Download the cover
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:issue.thumb];
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url] autorelease];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:issue.thumb parameters:nil];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        issue.thumb_location = filePath;

        NSLog(@"issue.thumb_location: %@", filePath);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED");
    }];
        [operation start];
    }
}
```

getOrDownloadCover:issue can be called 20 times in a row, so I would need to put all my requests into a queue, and once the queue is completed, it should still be able to save the path (or just send out a notification, since I already know what the path is)

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) to an object you can get the instance of at any point in your application, for example in your appDelegate. Then just add the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to this queue like:

```
[[(AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate operartionQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

Just handle the saving in the completion block, either call a methode from this block on the main thread or post a [`NSNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

To call the main thread use GCD :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Call any method from on the instance that created the operation here.
    [self updateGUI]; // example
});
```

Comment: Cool, but I am more worried about how to handle the saving of the path, or when I send out a notification, how will I know for wich Issue this was done?
Is there a way to save some data to the AFHTTPRequestOperation?

Comment: When you call the issue object in the block it will take the one that is in the passed when you call the method. Blocks will copy the object for using within the block. I suggest you read [Getting Started with Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, blocks are all kinda new to me, but I'll figure it out

Comment: Once your go block you never go back ;)

Comment: :) I've been reading through the documentation, but I can't figure out what you mean with "Blocks will copy the object", for instance in my case, how does the block know it needs to copy this Issue? It's never mentioned to the block in any way, expect that it's passed to the method.

Comment: If you use the `issue` instance variable within your block it will be retained for you, since it is used by the block and is in the function scope. (sorry thought it copied the object but looks like it will retain the object).

Comment: Great, it's starting to make some sense now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but...

Instead of using your own operationQueue you could use AFHTTPClient's operationQueue. Enqueue single operations with enqueueHTTPOperation or enqueue an array of operations with enqueueBatchOperations (I'm recalling these method names from memory, likely off a little).

As far as storing data specific to each operation, you could subclass AFHTTPRequestOperation and set properties for the path you'd like to store. Something like this.