# Downloading Files in queue using AFNetworking in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, afnetworking

I need to download multiple files in queue. Right now my code is working and all files are downloading simultaneously, However i need to download one file at a time, and all other files are in queue, below is code, please let me know what i doing wrong. I just need to download one file at a time and all other file should be in queue.

```
         AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:videoURL];
         [httpClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
         for (NSURL *videoString in videoArray) {

             NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoString];

             AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];
             [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 if(operation.response.statusCode == 200) {

                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Successfully Downloaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alertView show];

                  }

             }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                 if(operation.response.statusCode!= 200) {

                     UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Error While Downloaded" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alertView show];
                 }
             }];

             [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

             [operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {

                 float percentDone = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile;

                 }
             }];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11666141/1106035

Comment: @user1237473 ..have you done this? if yes then please let me know caz i want do same thing and its very urgent.thx

Answer (score 1):

To limit the queue to one Operation at a time,

you could try adding dependencies between each operation before you queue them.

Like this

`[Operation2 addDependency:Operation1];`

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you add dependency between two operations say operation1 and operation2 before adding to queue then the operation2 will not start until operation1 is finished or cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

use dispatch queues(GCD) after the block `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:`

like following way:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// Call any method from on the instance that created the operation here.
  [self doSomework]; // example
 });
```